# How to write where clause with combination of AND & OR

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to use query like below

```
( type = 1 OR type = 3 ) AND number = +9199123456
```

or below one

```
( type = 1 AND number = +9199123456) OR ( type = 3 AND number = +9199123456)
```

In my code I wrote like

```
whereClause = CallLog.Calls.NUMBER + " = " + phNO + " AND ("+CallLog.Calls.TYPE + " = " + CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE + " OR " + CallLog.Calls.TYPE + " = " + CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE+")";
```

Thank you in advance. please help me .

Comment: Some one is down voted. may be he doesn't know to how to solve it. You can refer below solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of parentheses with AND/OR is correct.

Your problem is that phone numbers should not be stored as numbers because they are just strings of digits and other characters.

If the value in the database is a string, it will never compare as equal with a number.

To format a value as a string, you must quote it:

```
... WHERE number = '+12345'
```

Comment: Thank you, you saved me.

Comment: I do not know how to use LIKE. Is this right... number LIKE '%=99123456%' AND (type = 1 OR type = 3)

Comment: That depends on what you want to do. This searches for a substring (beginning with `=`).

Answer (score 1):

Your query is right. But 'number' column is a string ? You have a "+" before the phone number, try to use quotation marks.